# Is there a way to launch custom application in fullscreen mode on android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Basically i'm developing some sort of restricted launcher. I would like to be able to open for example native android Date Time Settings from my android application in fullscreen mode(so that notification bar would not be visible).

If it was my own activity - no problem - either xml for or requestWindowFeature.

But how to do  it if i'm launching another intent? :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Any way to pass in some kind of flags?

One way of doing this is to use *ActivityGroup* :

```
LocalActivityManager mgr = getLocalActivityManager();
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS);
Window w = mgr.startActivity("unique_per_activity_string", i);
View wd = w != null ? w.getDecorView() : null;
setContentView(wd);
```

This works fine, but as i want to mess with android native settings, i must have the android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS to be able to save those settings. And i cannot acquire this permission unless my app runs as system.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had same problem, do you have solution for this, please share

Comment: Any solution for this problem?